# sails.js - how can I acess session data in Model hook beforeCreate

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, orm, sails.js, waterline

I want to update a field 'owner' of a Model. The owner needs to be fetched from the session which contains the user who is currently logged in and is creating the Model.

I want something like this:

```
Model = {

  attributes: {

  },

  beforeCreate(values,next)
  {
    var owner_user_id  = req.session.user_id;
    values.owner = owner_user_id;
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure a lifecycle callback is the right place to do it? Because it's really not. What if tomorrow you'll need to use your model in a CLI task or something else sessionless? Besides, with the associations API coming, there will be, probably, a more elegant way to do it, but still outside of the model. So, for now I would just treat your reference as a simple value, set it in the action (from where you can access `req.session`) and pass to the constructor along with other properties, something like:

```
...
// Controller code
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    // Whatever gets you the values...

    values.owner = req.session.user_id;
    Model.create(values, function(err, model) {...});
  },
  // Other actions
}
...
```