# How to get access to req (request) property from service

Tags: node.js, session, express, sails.js

It is simple to get access to `session` property from the action of controller.

```
var SomeController = {
  someAction: function(req, res) {
    // no we have access to session object
    if (!req.session.hasOwnProperty('flash')) {
      req.session.flash = [];
    } 
  }
}
```

But I need to get access to `session` object from service.
Example file `app/services/my_servise.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  some_method: function() {
    // here at i need to get access to session object?
    // is it possible?   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853179/sailjs-use-session-param-in-model/22855255#22855255) for an extended discussion of why you can't access session params in model class methods; the exact same answer holds true for services.  The upshot is that you *must* pass the request object as an argument to your service method if you want access to the session in the service code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution very much depends on when my_service.js is called and for what purposes it is used. Here is the easiest one:

```
var my_service, SomeController;
my_service = require('./services/my_service.js'); // Assuming this module is in the /app directory.
SomeController = {
    'someAction': function(req, res) {
        if (!req.session.hasOwnProperty('flash')) {
            req.session.flash = [];
        }
        my_service.some_method(req);
    }
}
```

/app/services/my_service.js:

```
module.exports = {
    'some_method': function (req) {
        // use req.session
    }
};
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please explain my_service.js its usage a little more.

Comment: Note, you don't have to `require` the service, as Sails globalizes all service files automatically.

Comment: @ScottGress Thanks, I hadn't seen it had to work with sails.js. I'm not familiar with that framework though.

Comment: I need my_service.js for saving and getting access to flash messages. 
Example: I send POST request to `/user/login` action. From data is valid. Then i redirect user from current action to `/user/welcome`, and i want to show some message which was generated in `/user/login` action. I need to use sessions fore temporary storing of lash messages.