# How to get session parameters in afterCreate of sails model

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js, after-create

I want to get get current logged in user in a models `afterCreate` callback. In controller, current logged in user is found form the request header-`req.user`. But in model's life-cycle callback the session header is not passed. Is there any way to find the current user from model?

I want something like this:

```
afterCreate: function(record,next){
    var currentUser=this.req.user.id; //want to get the request header here with logged in user
    AnotherModel.create({something:record.something, createdBy:currentUser}).exec(function(err, anotherRecord){
        next()
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The req object is not available within the model (for reasons I will not go into).

But your issue is a common one. What many people have done is create a policy that will set that param automatically on the params being passed to the model.

Here are a bunch of related questions and answers

[sails.js Use session param in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853179/sails-js-use-session-param-in-model)

[Is it possible to access a session variable directly in a Model in SailsJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457552/is-it-possible-to-access-a-session-variable-directly-in-a-model-in-sailsjs)

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/556

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/787

[Sails Google Group Discussion on the topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sailsjs/session$20model/sailsjs/sSYNtE8nN44/IvQzU9J4IksJ)