# In sails.js, how to access session variables in method beforeCreate of model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

This is my user model now before create user entity I want to auto give value session variable to createdBy and updatedBY.

```
       module.exports = {
            autoPK: false,
         attributes: {
                id:{columnName:'ID', type: 'integer', autoIncrement: true,  primaryKey: true},
                employeeId:{columnName:'EMPLOYEE_ID', type: 'string',unique : true},
                firstName:{columnName:'FIRST_NAME', type: 'string'},
                lastName:{columnName:'LAST_NAME', type: 'string'},
                createdBy:{columnName:'CREATED_BY', model: 'user'},
                updatedBy:{columnName:'CREATED_BY', model: 'user'},
        },
        beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {

        values.createdBy=req.session.userId;
        values.updatedBy=req.session.userId;
        return values;
          },
       beforeUpdate: function(values, cb) {

        values.updatedBy=req.session.userId;
        return values;
          },
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. Found some relevant resources that may help point you in the right direction. Unfortunately, there isn't great support to have sails automatically set UpdatedBy and CreatedBy properties on models.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855255/3085 - Use session param in model
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20998496/3085 - Access session data in Model hook
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274325/3085 - Overriding blueprints
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21703180/3085 - Using model.js for model inheritance